# Visual Web Developer 2010 and Nunit

Tags: vwdexpress

How would I integrate NUnit with VWD 2010 to create a MVC test project when I create a new project? I tried the procedure I did for 2008 ([How do I add NUnit as a test framework option for ASP.NET MVC to Visual Web Developer 2008 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666941/how-do-i-add-nunit-as-a-test-framework-option-for-asp-net-mvc-to-visual-web-devel)) but it will not bring a dialog box to create the unit test project.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround to start; not elegant but works.

I've both VWD 2008 & VWD 2010. I created a project using 2008 then using a tool that I found at http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/10/19/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx converted MVC 1.0 to MVC 2.0.

Once I'm in VWD 2010 - basic things works (tests, code completion, creation of controllers from Test project - that's all I tested so far).

Comment: Have you figured out a better way to do this?