# How can I set up an ASP .NET MVC application with NUnit unit tests in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?

Tags: c#, nunit, visual-web-developer

I understand that the Express edition doesn't template unit test projects... but being a complete newbie to Microsoft dev tools, I can't figure out how to set up the necessary things manually either.  So could someone please walk me through how to get NUnit going?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually quite simple:

1. Download NUnit.
2. Set up a new console application or class library in Visual Studio.
3. Add a reference to the `nunit.framework`.
4. Add a reference to the class library you want to test (put the code you want to test into a separate class library)
5. [Follow a tutorial](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.4) on how to create your own tests.

See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/04/28/updated-nunit-templates-for-asp-net-mvc-1-0-rtm.aspx) for a sample MVC 1.0 project and sample templates, or [this link](http://blogs.tnjconsulting.com/users/jason/weblog/eaabd/MVC_NUnit_Template_for_VS_2010.html) for MVC 2.0 templates.

Comment: Sure. See this link for a sample project and some sample templates: http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/04/28/updated-nunit-templates-for-asp-net-mvc-1-0-rtm.aspx

Comment: Doesn't work for me... there's a clear reference to version 9.0 of some framework, and of course I'm using 2010, which is version 10.0. So there's an error when trying to instantiate the template. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: In that case, you can download the templates here: http://blogs.tnjconsulting.com/users/jason/weblog/eaabd/MVC_NUnit_Template_for_VS_2010.html

Comment: Ok, now I'm baffled. I followed that process and nothing changed. The .reg file that came with those templates seems to be for Visual Studio non-Express, but I made the obvious changes, still nothing.

Comment: This old question may have some tips for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666941/how-do-i-add-nunit-as-a-test-framework-option-for-asp-net-mvc-to-visual-web-devel

Comment: So, can you describe how to manually construct an MVC 2.0 NUnit test project?  I'm happy to build stuff from source even.  I don't understand precisely what you mean by point #4 above, either.

Comment: Read the ASP.NET MVC Framework Unleashed book, which uses TDD to develop an MVC blog site. Although it uses VS Tests instead of NUnit, it is a great example of how you can develop your own tests. Source code is freely available. http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0672329980

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666941/how-do-i-add-nunit-as-a-test-framework-option-for-asp-net-mvc-to-visual-web-devel had the answer... I had everything in place except the right registry magic.

Comment: Ok, so it still isn't working... I don't get any test project materials unpacked.