# NUnit Testing Framework for MVC 3 Projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit

I am using *Visual Web Developer 2010*.  I have installed *NUnit*, and I'm trying to get it so that *NUnit* is a selectable testing framework when you create an *ASP.NET MVC 3* project.

Since I am using *Visual Web Developer*, I do not have access to *MSTest*.  What do I need to do to get *NUnit* loaded as a Test Framework so I can add it as a project based off of a template when I create an MVC 3 project?

Comment: Seems, like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137/asp-net-mvc-and-nunit

Comment: @AlexanderYezutov That's over 3 years old, and I'm sure there could possibly be an easier way currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may checkout the [following template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7f3bdc82-f418-41aa-ad15-f1d6f89df47a). It's for VS2010 Professional and higher since VWD 2010 do not support extensions.

Comment: Thanks for that link, Darin.  I did try that out yesterday, but I can't seem to get the *.vsix file to load into the extension manager.  It says I don't have the right program to load that file type.  I extracted the manifest file from the vsix file and even added my edition, and still nothing.

Comment: Should I just succomb to having to add a separate test class library project manually and rewrite all of the basic unit tests and just work off of that?  I guess that would be fine, I would just like to have seen the test framework get wired into MVC 3.

Comment: @Shark, indeed, it doesn't work with VWD 2010 as it doesn't support extensions.

Comment: Darin, ok that's all I needed to hear.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Darin, do you use NUnit?  What are your thoughts on it?  I've just started playing with it, but it seems pretty promising.  What more could you want in a testing framework??  I think I may stick with it.

Comment: @Shark, no, I don't use NUnit. I use mainly MSTest or XUnit (for open source projects where I don't have VS edition which supports MSTest). But NUnit is a very good unit testing framework that I have used in the past. Personally I don't think that the unit test framework that you are using matters that much.